# Is there any way to select the correct peaks of a histogram formed from an image of lines?

Tags: python, opencv, scipy

I have some code that makes histograms of an image. I am currently using the scipy method `find_peaks` to find the peaks but it is detecting some redundant values also. Here's the code I am using :

```py
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
...
hist = cv2.reduce(threshed,1, cv2.REDUCE_AVG).reshape(-1)
peaks, _ = find_peaks(hist)
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))

plt.plot(hist)
plt.plot(peaks, hist[peaks], "x")
plt.show()
...
```

Here's the output Histplot with Peaks :

[image: output]

Suppose I want the values only above 20 but can't hardcode it as the limit is different for every image.

Comment: I really don't undsertand your question, you can set a threshold in the find_peaks function

Comment: Setting a threshold would mean setting it at around 20 maybe? But some peaks (for lines with just one or two words) would be lower than this.

Answer (score 0):

Tried using prominence = 30 and it worked. Cuts off the noise and gives good results.

```
peaks, _ = find_peaks(hist,prominence=30)
```

Tweaking with the prominence and distance metric is required to get the best peaks in the list.